# GoodData Export Reports API Call results in incomplete file

Tags: rest, gooddata

I've developed a method that does the following steps, in this order:
1) Get a report's metadata via /gdc/md//obj/
2) From that, get the report definition and use that as payload for a call to /gdc/xtab2/executor3
3) Use the result from that call as payload for a call to /gdc/exporter/executor
4) Perform a GET on the returned URI to download the generated CSV

So this all works fine, but the problem is that I often get back a blank CSV or an incomplete CSV. My workaround has been to put a sleep() in between getting the URI back and actually calling a GET on the URI. However, as our data grows, I have to keep increasing the delay on this, and even then it is no guarantee that I got complete data. Is there a way to make sure that the report has finished exporting data to the file before calling the URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that export runs as asynchronous task - result on the URL returned in payload of `POST` to `/gdc/exporter/executor` (in form of `/gdc/exporter/result/{project-id}/{result-id}`) is available after exporter task finishes its job.

If the task has not been done yet, `GET` to `/gdc/exporter/result/{project-id}/{result-id}` should return status code `202` which means "we are still exporting, please wait".

So you should periodically poll on the result URL until it returns status `200` which will contain a payload (or `40x`/`50x` if something wrong happened).

Comment: To clarify, what I did was `POST` to `/gdc/exporter/executor`, which gives back a URI to call to retrieve the file I want. To check that it's done, I did a `GET` against the returned URI, which gives back a `202` or `200` (unless something went wrong). I continue to poll that until I get a 200, at which point I grab the content returned.